# Extract all keywords within a text and split into 3 groups every match

Tags: c#, regex

```
^(.*)(th)(.*)$
```

That's what I did, but it's doesn't catch all the `th` keywords within a text.

I will give some examples how must works.

#### Example #1:

Text: *Th*e Book *Th*eif

Match 1:

- Group 1. ''
- Group 2. 'Th'
- Group 3. ' Book '

Match 2:

- Group 1. ''
- Group 2. 'Th'
- Group 3. 'ief'

---

#### Example #1:

Text: Harry Potter and *th*e Order of *th*e Phoenix

Match 1:

- Group 1. 'Harry Potter and '
- Group 2. 'th'
- Group 3. 'e Order of '

Match 2:

- Group 1. ''
- Group 2. 'th'
- Group 3. 'e Phoenix'

---

If you someone wonder why I want 3 groups in such a way, that's because i'm trying to replace the `keyword` with `<mark>keywrod</mark>` and keep everything same, but I have trouble making the regex pattern by myself.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It seems all you need is `s=s.Replace(keyword, $"<mark>{keyword}</mark>");`

Comment: I'm not sure if the matches you provided are those from your regex and arent working, or if thats desired output? The question is not very clear.

Comment: The example I have provided are desired output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew omgggg you are totally true, how I hadn't thought of it earlier.

Comment: What do you want to do if there are more than one "th" in your input.  The patterns you are describing are [stuff1][th][stuff2].  But, what you have in "The Book Thief" is [null-stuff1][th][stuff2][th][stuff3].  What you seem to want to do is use [stuff2] as the trailing match on the first "th" and the leading match on the second.  What you might do is iterate over the string, throwing away everything up to & including the first "th" match, and doing it again until you run out of "th"-es.

Comment: Oh, I just re-read your question, after re-reading @WiktorStribiżew 's answer, and, yeah, do what he said, if what he's guessing you want to do is right.  And, if your keywords are static (I.e., they don't need a Regex), use StringBuilder.Replace, not string.Replace; it's a better solution for a lot of Replace calls.

Comment: @Flydog57 thanks for your answer, string.Replace and StringBuilder.Replace seems they do the job, but i'm still interested what might be the regex pattern. In "The Book Theif" there should be 2 matches: 1st match: [group1][th][group3]; 2nd match: [group1][th][group2]. group1 in 2nd match should be empty string.

Comment: Iliyan, `^(.*)(th)(.*)$` cannot find two matches since it matches a whole string having `th` and placing the text before, `th`, and text after into separate groups. I do not understand the problem here, sorry. Probably it is related to a whole word search. Cf. `@"^(.*)\b(th)\b(.*)$"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check on the next regex `(?i)(.*?)(th)((?:(?!th).)*)`.

Try it online [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fi%29%28.*%3f%29%28th%29%28%28%3f%3a%28%3f!th%29.%29*%29&i=The+Book+Theif%0d%0aReady+Player+One%0d%0aHarry+Potter+and+the+Order+of+the+Phoenix).

To get an explanation of the regex, please click [here](https://regex101.com/r/KeHamo/2).